# Rackspace Cloud Monitoring API

Tags: rackspace-cloud

I was looking at the [cloud monitoring API](http://docs.rackspace.com/cm/api/v1.0/cm-devguide/content/overview.html) guide of Rackspace. If anyone has already been through it and/or has used it, can you please tell me whether it is possible to get stats relating to average consumption of resources by my cloud?

Example, can I use the API to answer questions such as how many hours my cloud/instance has been running in the past month, or how much memory on an average it has used in the past month, etc.

I am very new to this - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Rackspace Cloud Monitoring agent for Linux is currently in an early access beta. You can definitely get memory statistics using this agent, as well as uptime. You could also write a custom plugin script to pull data from the cloud servers API regarding bandwidth, hours of usage, etc.

[See this for more information.](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/taxonomy/term/1777)